# Save custom meta-box all the fields data at once

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I have a custom meta-box on `new-post` page which allows user to add photos continuously. He can add more and more (Any number of photos).

So, I have a problem when saving this data. Because, the number of fields is not same.

My code is as follows:

```
if( isset( $_POST[ 'photo-title-1' ] ) ) {

    $photos = array(
        0 => array($_POST[ 'photo-title-0' ], $_POST[ 'photo-url-0' ], $_POST[ 'photo-desc-0' ]),
        1 => array($_POST[ 'photo-title-1' ], $_POST[ 'photo-url-1' ], $_POST[ 'photo-desc-1' ]),
        2 => array($_POST[ 'photo-title-2' ], $_POST[ 'photo-url-2' ], $_POST[ 'photo-desc-2' ])
        ............................................
        ............................................
        ............................................
         n => array($_POST[ 'photo-title-n' ], $_POST[ 'photo-url-n' ], $_POST[ 'photo-desc-n' ])

    );

    $serialized_array = serialize($photos);
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'photos', sanitize_text_field($serialized_array) );

}
```

As you can see, there can be **n** number of fields and what's the way of saving all of them at once?

Comment: Why not just save arrays via a `foreach` loop, instead of naming each field uniquely?

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so, how to check isset() ? Include isset() inside the foreach too ?

Comment: I'm sorry could you please be little bit clearer ? This is a multidimensional array. I have no idea how to loop through that.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate with a `while` in the `POST` array:

```
$sum = 0;

while( isset($_POST['photo-title-' . $sum]) ){

    $photos[] = array(

        $_POST[ 'photo-title-' . $sum ],
        $_POST[ 'photo-url-' . $sum ],
        $_POST[ 'photo-desc-' . $sum ]

    );

    $sum++;

}

$serialized_array = serialize($photos);
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'photos', sanitize_text_field($serialized_array) );
```

**EDIT**

Following the comments, the `POST Array` could not contain all the fields, there is an update to solve this:

```
$reg = '/^photo\-(title|url|desc)\-(\d+)$/';

$filter = preg_grep($reg, array_keys($_POST));

$photos = array();

foreach($filter as $param){

    $index = preg_replace($reg, '$2', $param);

    if( !isset($photos[$index]) ) $photos[$index] = array();

    $photos[$index][$param] = $_POST[$param];

}

$serialized_array = serialize($photos);
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'photos', sanitize_text_field($serialized_array) );
```

If you want consecutive indexes in the `Array`, you can add:

```
$photos = array_values($photos);
```

Comment: Thanks! It almost worked! But, there's a problem. Let's say the filed named 'photo-title-4' was deleted by the user, so, it doesn't go beyond 4 because 4 is not set. So, the fields named like 'photo-title-5' and higher don't get submitted. This is because it checks if it's set before going inside the loop. Any solution ?

Comment: The user can delete any field? For example the data could be 1, 4 and 5 and the 2 and 3 fields deleted?

Comment: Yes, that's right!. He can add any number of fields. And delete any if changes his mind (middle ones as well)

Comment: Ok Thanks! I'll wait :)

Comment: Thanks a million! It worked! I didn't use the exact code you provided. I did some changes but it is you who showed me the way.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that ;)